# VirtualBox VRDP server doesn't start on Windows

Tags: virtualbox

I've installed VirtualBox 4.1.8 on a Windows 7 Ultimate host system. I've set up an Arch Linux VM that starts just fine from the VirtualBox GUI. However, when I try to start it with `VBoxHeadless --startvm <vm_name>` it prints the following

```
Oracle VM VirtualBox Headless Interface 4.1.6
(C) 2008-2011 Oracle Corporation
All rights reserved.
```

and then it just sits there. I never get the `VRDE server is listening on port 3389` message like when I start a headless VM on a Linux machine.

Do I have to configure anything else in order to get the VRDE server to run?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the extension pack is installed, the message means the RDP server is running and that means it is waiting for a connection.

You just need to use MSTSC.exe to connect: hit WindowsKey+R to open a 'Run' dialog and then type MSTSC.exe 1.2.3.4:1234 (where the numbers are your guest's IP address and port number (after the ':').

Assuming you haven't changed the default port (3389) then the IP address will probably be 127.0.0.2 from the host machine.  Check this works first.
If this works from the host machine then you can either use port forwarding with NAT or bridged adapter mode to connect from a different machine (both have Pros/Cons - Google it).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the "VM VirtualBox Extension Pack" (for the version of the VirtualBox you have installed) in order to get the VRDE support.

For the guest machine(s) you should activate it and you may also change the port if you check under "settings", "Screen" and then "Remote desktop" that the server is activated.